# truncar decimal

Tags: php, function

***QUIERO REDONDEAR UN NUMERO, PERO LO QUE QUIERO ES PONER UNA CONDICIÓN ***

```
  Math.Truncate(6.847457) //resultado 6
```

***Pero este me trunca todos los números yo solo quiero que trunque el 5 y los demás si los redondee  ***

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no se que lenguaje es ese (Math.truncate) pero no es php. Te doy la respuesta en php, que es la que pides según la etiqueta que has marcado:

```
$valor //tu valor
$parte_entera = (int) $valor;
if($parte_entera == 5){
    $valor = $parte_entera;
}
else{
    $valor = round($valor);
}
```

Otra forma (lo mismo en realidad):

```
$valor = (floor($valor) == 5) ? 5 : round($valor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el método `round()` de php. Este método acepta tres parámetros: valor, precisión y modo.

Con el tercer parámetro, modo, puedes lograr lo que deseas así:

```
if($numero == 5){
 $numero = round($numero, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
}
```

Aquí la documentación del método: http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php